# How to keep my past self from freaking out when I go back to see him?

Tags: time-travel

Utilizing 17 9v batteries, a large speaker, a series of rotating magnets and some weird alien technology that landed in my yard, I have created a time machine! (I'd tell you how it works, but the only hint I can legally give you is that Mr. Peabody and Sherman were way off on the method, but accurate on the theory. Space-time laws are such a bummer.)Only problem is, I'm stuck here since I hit a tree an reentry to time and the alien technology is broken, and I'm supposed to be several years in the future. I know that my past 16 year old self has already received this alien technology, but right now is stuck at home during COVID. I know that in two hours the parents will leave for walmart and my siblings are going with them, so I have a way to get in.

BUT I also know that past me was a weird kid, and has a laser pointer, a BB gun, and a homemade flash-bang with himself at all times and there is a .22 and a shotgun in the house as well. I'd like not to get blinded, shot, and deafened by past me, so I have to somehow get past past me to grab the alien technology and then out. Problem is, past me has the alien technology under lock and key and has the only key. So I have to get the key from past me, grab the alien technology, and then get out. Once I get back to my time, I can duplicate the alien technology and send the original or a duplicate right back to past me, so it will never have been gone.

If you've watched any time travel movies, you probably know that talking to your past/future selves isn't smart, but right now that seems like the only option. Any advice on how to not freak out past me and convince him to give me the alien technology?

Comment: Approach yourself that time you were *really* stoned, and nothing could freak you out...except wiggling your fingers. Just, whatever you do, stay far away from your much-younger-and-hotter mom while seeking help from Doc to repair your DeLorean.

Comment: It looks like your world is already created and you're wanting us to write a scene set in this world for you.

Comment: Freaking out? Did you happen to suffer any facial burns since you were 16 years old?

Answer (score 2):

#### Past you is too crazy to negotiate with

Nobody carrys flash bangs to the shops just in case, even in the craziest gun nut parts of America this is paranoia to the extreme. Who takes a flash bang and bb gun to school?

Grab a taser and a bag of weed / booze / porn. When hes home alone knock on the door and say you have a delivery for his parents, they've prepaid for it and he needs to keep it safe. He'll think hes got the jackpot, when hes distracted, taser him.

Take your thing, come back and repair the timeline.

Comment: What if... this is all causal? What if he wasn’t crazy in his childhood, and hadn’t even thought to amass all these defensive weapons, before some **stranger showed up at his house, gave him a porn mag, shot him point-blank with a taser, then stole his shi*t**?! Perhaps this is really how things went down, and he screwed his own childhood up, badly.

Answer (score 0):

**Forget your past self**

Wait for future future you to turn up with the replacement that he knows you need right about now so you can go home.

When you get home, make a copy and go back in time to help past future you get home.